# Where should I do message resolution in Biztalk?

Tags: biztalk

Let's say I have a flat file containing incoming messages. Where would the appropriate place be to inject the logic that takes identifying information from the message and sets primary key properties to link it to internal record IDs. For example, to map a customer's version of order ID into our internal order ID.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking to do a *conversion* of the incoming id to the internal id before sending the further along.

There are multiple places to do this.

You could do it in a pipeline component that either reads directly from its run-time configuration or from a database. You could also do it in a orchestration.

The easiest and most suitable place to do is probably however in a transformation map. Just make sure not to hard-code the transformation table (what id maps to one of you internal ids) as these usually change a lot. Have the map do a lookup ion a database for example to find the matching id.

Doing these kind of tasks in a map compared to the other options gives you a bit more flexibility as you can then apply the map directly in receive or send port. So if you don't need to do any workflow based logic you can use a messaging pattern and skip any orchestrations (always preferable).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing this type of conversion in a map.